# How do I correctly set up a cron job on shared hosting for a Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

I set up a cron job to run 'php artisan schedule:run' on Namecheap. Running the cron job in the Terminal triggers the scheduled commands and outputs the result for each or states that no commands are ready to run when none are, but on its own, it doesn't seem to run.

Namecheap says the cron ran but may not have triggered the commands, and that the problem may be with my scripts. According to them,

> script wasn't started, may be caused due to incorrect settings between your script and created cron job.

I did get an email with this content though:

```
In ArgvInput.php line 264:
                                           
  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  
                                           

X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.34
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

which may mean that the scripts were triggered, but I have no idea what this points to.

My expectation is that similar to the Terminal output, the email should provide information on each command that ran (or that didn't run) and the output corresponding to each one. I don't understand how my script could be the issue if they ran when called from the Terminal.

My cron job:

```
0   15  *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/user-name/project-folder/artisan schedule:run
```

Several other ways of specifying the cron job also work such as:

```
0   15  *   *   * cd /home/user-name/project-folder &amp;&amp; php artisan schedule:run
```

What can I do to get this working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that the timezone in the app (config/app.php) matches with the server time resolved this issue for me. With this, once the cron job runs, any due commands will be triggered.